# converge in probability of the mean of summation of random variables if the summation is taken over moving intervals

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-limit-theorems

This is simplified from the assumptions in many papers regarding the existence of limit distribution of a least square estimator.

Assume $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of random variables such that the mean converge in probability to some real number $c$:
$$\frac {x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}\to^p c$$

Is it true that $$\frac {\sum_{i=n/2}^{n/2+\sqrt n}x_i}{\sqrt n}\to^pc?$$

or can we say as $n\to\infty$:
$$\frac {\sum_{i=n/2}^{n/2+\sqrt n}x_i}{\sqrt n}=O_p(1)?$$